# In a box are n red socks and n+1 blue socks. I choose 2 socks. Use a proof to show that I am twice as likely to pick one of each rather than 2 blue.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

> In a box are $n$ red socks and $n+1$ blue socks. I choose $2$ socks. Use a proof to show that I am twice as likely to pick one of each rather than $2$ blue.

I am unsure which combinatorial proof to use. This looks like pigeonhole but I don't know how I would use it.

Comment: Try for $n=1$..

Comment: Have you tried calculating the probabilities of choosing one of each and the probability of choosing two blue socks?

Comment: For my assignment I was explicitly asked to use a combinatorial proof that we have gone over in class. These include pigeonhole, Pascal's triangle, corollary 1, etc.

Comment: When you calculate those probabilities, you have to use the binomial coefficients in Pascal's triangle.

Comment: I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to find the actual probabilities:

1. If you choose a blue sock first (without replacement) then you are then equally likely to choose a blue or a red sock second since there remain $n$ of each. So blue followed by blue is as likely as blue followed by red.
2. But the socks are exchangeable, so the total probability of a mixed pair is twice the probability of a blue sock followed by a red sock,  and so (by 1) twice the probability of an all blue pair.

Answer (score 1):

The denominator will remain the same in both cases, so just comparing numerators is enough

- For blue pair, numerator $= (n+1)n$
- For mixed socks which can come as $BR\; or\; RB,\;\; 2*(n+1)n \;\;...[QED]$

Answer (score 0):

I would say this is what a combinatorial argument would look like.

Number the red and blue socks: $r_1,\cdots,r_n,b_1,\cdots,b_{n+1}$ (respectively). So when we take two socks out we will have one of the possible pairs $(r_i, r_j)$, $(r_i, b_k)$, or $(b_i, b_j)$, where $i≠ j$ and the possible values are in the obvious ranges in each case. Now count how many combinations of each there are:

For two reds we have $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$, for two blues $\frac{(n+1)n}{2}$, and for one blue, one red we have $n(n+1)$.

From now it's clear what to do.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

One red one blue is

$\dfrac{\binom{n}{1}\binom{n+1}{1}}{\binom{2n+1}{2}}$ which is
$\dfrac{n+1}{2n+1}$.

Two blue is $\dfrac{\binom{n+1}{2}}{\binom{2n+1}{2}}$ which is $\dfrac{n+1}{2(2n+1)}$

and we proved that $P(1 $and$ 1)$=$2P(2 red)$!

Comment: You meant to say two blue rather than two red.